# Optical Vortex Generation Using a Spiral Phase Plate (SPP)

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, vortex

I know it is possible to generate an optical vortex using a spp. The vortex will a have twist direction following the sign of its topological charge integer $\ell$. But how is the sign of $\ell$ assigned? Is it dependent on the spp geometry? It means that if I want to inverse the sign of $\ell$ shall I use a spp with reversed geometry (reversed "spiring" angle)?

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the sign of the vortex charge depends on the SPP spiral's handedness.